# error "List does not exist"

Tags: sharepoint-2010

> I had error when access **SharePoint** sites out of the server , as when I
>   try to add new document or did any action this error displayed although
>   it worked well in **SharePoint** server

[image]

Comment: Have you configured alternate access mappings?

Comment: what do y mean with alternate access mappings ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepoint_strategery/archive/2013/05/25/alternate-access-mappings-explained.aspx

Comment: Did you look in the Event log or the sharepoint event viewer what is the exactly the error ? which list you are trying to access ? can you check the Alternate access mapping as well as the URL generated for that list ?\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Yevgeniy made a good suggestion. 
I assume you mean by 'outside' the server,  users are trying  to view the page on a different URL? If so, it might be the URLs to access the site 'outside SharePoint' are not configured correctly.

I would suggest a few things to start with:

1. When you say it works 'in SharePoint server' does this mean that the *whole* site is accessible, with no problems? But using a different URL (i.e. host header?), fails - for just this one page with the list or the whole site?

Check  you have Alternate Access Mappings configured correctly as suggested above - check that the URL is setup correctly in any AAM zones defined, and that the authentication (e.g. Anonymous, Forms whatever required) is also setup too. This is all done in Central Administration.

1. If AAM setup correctly, check if you have any firewall or other network security that may block access to the site (again, assuming users are routed externally?)
2. Does the problem page or list (or the subsite it is within) have any unique security permissions? 
   You can check for the site via Site Actions | Site Permissions - if it does not have unique permissions, you will see a 'This Web site inherits permissions from its parent.' message.

If the List has unique permissions, you can check by going to the list page, and clicking 'Library Permissions' on the Library grouping on the Library Tools section of the ribbon.